# What commands are blocked by setting "commands: restricted" for a step target in an azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

The [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#task) indicate you can restrict logging commands in their yaml schema doc:

```
steps:
- task: string  # reference to a task and version, e.g. "VSBuild@1"
  displayName: string  # friendly name displayed in the UI
  name: string  # identifier for this step (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
  condition: string
  continueOnError: boolean  # 'true' if future steps should run even if this step fails; defaults to 'false'
  enabled: boolean  # whether to run this step; defaults to 'true'
  target:
    container: string # where this step will run; values are the container name or the word 'host'
    commands: enum  # whether to process all logging commands from this step; values are `any` (default) or `restricted`
    settableVariables: string # what variables are allowed; defaults to all; can be `none` or a list of allowed vars
  timeoutInMinutes: number
  inputs: { string: string }  # task-specific inputs
  env: { string: string }  # list of environment variables to add
```

It does not indicate which logging commands will be blocked. Neither does the logging commands documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops

What commands does restricted block and which remain unblocked?

Comment: Hi, I am testing it, and will share the result here later.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it, but I can't find the difference in the log, I have submitted the feedback to GitHub doc team, you could refer to this [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/10525) for more details, and I will follow the ticket and let you know if it has any updates.